# Invalid object name 'Import_Table'. in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

After creating my database using the script shown below, if I execute 'select * from import_table' it gives error saying "Invalid object name 'Import_Table'" . I know it will run  perfectly if I change the query to 'select * from hrobuser.import_table' , which is not possible from our end to suffix the the user name(hrobuser) in the query.

So can anyone tell me that is this the only way to execute or is there any other solution for this particular issue.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
USE master
GO

SET DATEFORMAT MDY



CREATE DATABASE HROB3_0

IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT name FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE name = 'HROB3_0' )
BEGIN
RAISERROR( N'Database was not successfully created. Review the script for incorrect parameters.', 20, -1) WITH LOG;
END;
GO

--###################################
-- Alter Database and set the options
--###################################

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
--Automatic Options
ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO

-- Cursor Options
ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO

-- Miscellaneous Options
ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO

--Recovery Options

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO

--State Options
ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET READ_WRITE
GO

ALTER DATABASE HROB3_0 SET MULTI_USER
GO

--########################################
-- Create login user and schema
--########################################
USE HROB3_0
GO

CREATE LOGIN hrobuser WITH PASSWORD = 'imagenow', DEFAULT_DATABASE = HROB3_0, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=us_english, CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF
GO

CREATE USER hrobuser FOR LOGIN hrobuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=hrobuser
GO

CREATE SCHEMA hrobuser AUTHORIZATION hrobuser
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'hrobuser'
GO

USE MASTER
GO

GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO hrobuser
GO

USE HROB3_0
GO

EXECUTE AS user = 'hrobuser'
GO



CREATE TABLE IMPORT_TABLE
( 
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR(10) not null,
    EMPLOYEE_NAME_FIRST VARCHAR(20),
    EMPLOYEE_NAME_LAST VARCHAR(20),
    SUPERVISOR_NAME_FULL VARCHAR(40),
    SUPERVISOR_EMAIL_WORK VARCHAR(70),
    EMPLOYEE_HOMEADDRESS_STREET VARCHAR(20),
    EMPLOYEE_HOMEADDRESS_APT VARCHAR(20),
    EMPLOYEE_HOMEADDRESS_CITY VARCHAR(20),
    EMPLOYEE_HOMEADDRESS_STATE VARCHAR(30),
    EMPLOYEE_HOMEADDRESS_ZIP int,
    EMPLOYEE_PHONE_HOME int,
    EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_PERSONAL VARCHAR(70),
    EMPLOYEE_TITLE VARCHAR(20),
    LOCATION_REFERENCE_1 VARCHAR(20),
    LOCATION_REFERENCE_2 VARCHAR(20),
    REFERENCE_1 VARCHAR(30),
    REFERENCE_2 VARCHAR(30),
    WORK_STATE VARCHAR(20),
    DATE_HIRED DATE,
    ADDITIONAL_EMP_INFO_1 VARCHAR(150),
    ADDITIONAL_EMP_INFO_2 VARCHAR(150),
    ADDITIONAL_EMP_INFO_3 VARCHAR(150),
    ADDITIONAL_EMP_INFO_4 VARCHAR(150),
    ADDITIONAL_EMP_INFO_5 VARCHAR(150),
    UNIQUE (EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your user has permission to create table in your database. If not then provide the same. 
Check the below code and hope this will help.

USE mydatabase
GRANT ALTER ON Schema :: DBO TO user_mydatabase
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO user_mydatabase
GO

and then you can add your code to execute as user "EXECUTE AS user = 'hrobuser' ......"